# Why are these equations describing the variance of residuals equivalent (single-factor model in finance)?

Tags: statistics, expected-value, finance, variance

[Residual Equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mElY.jpg)

The above equations describe the residual variance in the single-factor model in finance. I'm struggling to understand why they are equivalent, specifically why the fourth and fifth equations from the left are equal.

Comment: Expectation is linear (expectation of sum = sum of expectations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from linearity of expectation and the fact that $Ee_i=0$. The latter implies that $\sigma^2_{e_i}=E(e_i^2)$.